# MinGW install failed, does anyone know what went wrong?

Tags: gcc, mingw32, failed-installation

I installed gcc using MinGW using the following instructions: https://dev.to/gamegods3/how-to-install-gcc-in-windows-10-the-easier-way-422j

Unfortunately, typing gcc --version into cmd or powershell returns:

'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I have: opened a new cmd window, configured path correctly. I also did a folder search and discovered the installation files e.g. gcc-c++-6.3.0-1-mingw32-bin.tar.xz I unzipped one of these and the binaries are inside.

Just wondering if there is a way to fix this, or whether anyone knows of an easy was to automatically install all of these files.

Comment: "configured path correctly". Apparently not.

Comment: These instructions are garbage anyway. You want [this](https://www.msys2.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Alright I did some more exploring, and it turns out that my path was NOT configured correctly, sorry for this terrible post. It turns out that the files were installed in C:/User//bin and not C:/User//mingw/bin